# Cast quoted Text into Bigint in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

By using below query, i had tried to convert the Text column to Bigint.

```
select id::bigint  from TBL_Log limit 20;
```

But it gives the following error

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "562374398" SQL state: 22P02
```

Please suggest me, how to cast text into bigint

**Note**:
I had tried the following query also, but it also gives the same result

```
select cast(id as bigint)  from TBL_Log limit 20;
```

Comment: Well that works here: `select '562374398'::bigint; 562374398`.  There must be something else going on. Postgres version? Where are you running the query? What is the original value in the text column? In particular have you run `length` on the text value to see if there are hidden characters?

Comment: Are you saying the text value has quotes in it? Where did those come from?

Comment: If you have characters other than digits you need to remove them first. `select regexp_replace('"test3 45test"','\D','','g'); --345 `

Comment: @Bergi  The double quotes shown in the error message are added by the code which creates the error message, they are not part of the data which caused the error but are quoting that data.

Comment: It's possible that there is a non-printable character in that string.